# Java how to maintain sequence of scanned objects in an arraylist when values are updated

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

**I have a class that contains patient name and emergency level that implements comparable:**

```
class Patient implements Comparable<Patient>{
    private String name;
    private int emergencyLvl;

    public Patient(String name, int emergencyLvl)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.emergencyLvl = emergencyLvl;

    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;

    }
    public int getEmergencyLvl(){
        return this.emergencyLvl;

    }
    public  void  setEmergencyLvl(int updateLvl){
        this.emergencyLvl = updateLvl;

    }
    public void setName(String newName){
        this.name = newName;

    }
    public int compareTo(Patient p){

        int compareEmergency = ((Patient) p).getEmergencyLvl();

        return compareEmergency - this.emergencyLvl;

    **//I believe my error comes from here**




        }
}
```

**Lets say this is my input file:

```
3
0 david 30
0 may 60
1 david 30
2
```

*3 = number of query, 0 = new patient to be added into arraylist, 1 = update emergency level (example 30 + 30 = 60). 2 = print the Emergency level from Descending order and name.**

However, my program managed to scan and add new patient to the arraylist properly but whenever it requires updating of emergency level the sequence is wrong.

For example, before updating of david emergency level.The sequence is (may 60, david 30) 
but after updating of david emergency level since david arrives first then may thus the correct sequence should be (david 60, may 60).

Unfortunately, i fail to update the sequence correctly. 
Here is my main program:

UpdateEmergencyLvl:

```
void UpdateEmergencyLvl(String patientName, int incEmergencyLvl) {

        for(Patient p: a1){
            if(p.getName().equals(patientName)){
                int newEmergencyLvl = p.getEmergencyLvl() +
                incEmergencyLvl;
                p.setEmergencyLvl(newEmergencyLvl);

                }

            }

            Collections.sort(a1);

    }
```

Comment: No need to cast p to Patient in the compareTo - it already is a Patient as per the method signature

Comment: Yes, but that does not solve my case because i want to make the order of patients that comes in first to be correct. Since in my case David comes first ,but emergency updated later. however, after updating the emergency level is the same as May. But David comes first so david should print out first instead of May.

Comment: My code is fine when sort in descending order. But is wrong when maintaining of the order when two or more emergency level is the same.

Comment: Maybe adding an index of arrival you would be able to avoid the problem. FOr example, get the lines of the input file as index.

Comment: When compareTo returns 0 the order of the two elements compared remains unchanged. - Collections.sort(List<?>) `This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort. `

Comment: Yes i do understand the two elements compared remains and thats why i am asking how to resolve my situation in this case. i want the order to be changed when David arrives first after emergency level is updated to the same as May.

Comment: @zac from your last comment it follows that you want your ordering to depend on an information that the Patient class does not own nor has access to. Which is an impossible goal to achive. Define clearly what that information is (why would David come first ? Because it is the last updated Patient ? then your missing information is "time of the last update" or "line of the last upadte"). And add it to your compare method.

Comment: hi GPI, at the start David comes into hospital and was given emergency level 30. after david, MAY come into hospital and was given emergency level 60. Therefore, at this point MAY has a higher emergency level than david thus by right MAY should be treated first. However, during the day. David suddenly has sudden pain thus the nurse increase david emergency level by 30. therefore, david has 60 emergency level and is the same as MAY now. but david comes before MAY. thus when the query statement is executed David will be treated first followed by MAY. however, my code does not output thecorrectly

Comment: you need the info of arrival to do that, as I said, try to use the file lines as index, or add a column of hour of arrival, I don't see that info.

Comment: the given info in my input file is standard. i cant change it as it is given that way. so is there another way for example i create a counter index in my patient class ? but how do i make changes to my comparater method to check my index is < than other element of the same emergency level ?

Comment: or as you said to use the file line as index but how do i use the file line? i am new to scanner class

Comment: If you are adding the lines using a bufferedReader, just create an int, for example int index=0 before the bucle for reading the line, and do index ++ after reading each line in the bucle, then add that index to the info you use on the patients, ad a new attribute, for example, you have name and emergencylvl, you could add a new arrivalIndx attrribute to store that.

Comment: I'll make an answer for more detailed info for you.

Comment: thank you. i am using java scanner class to scan each line in input file. @Amnor

Comment: I posted an answer, I need the way you scan the files to complete the index part, please consider to add that code to the question.

Comment: i have add the scanner method into your code. could you please show me how to get the index of the line? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a new attribute to the class Patient, your new public Patient should look like this:

```
public Patient(String name, int emergencyLvl, int patIndx)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.emergencyLvl = emergencyLvl;
            this.patIndx = patIndx;

        }
```

Once this done, create a getter for index; and in your reading method you could just ad an int to this index. For the compare method, as the arrival index is more important than sharing the same emergencyLvl, I would do something like this:

```
public int compareTo(Patient p){

        int compareEmergency = ((Patient) p).getEmergencyLvl();

        int aux= compareEmergency - this.emergencyLvl;

        int compareIndex= ((Patient) p).getIndex();
        if(compareIndex>this.patIndx) aux=compareIndex-this.patIndx;
        return aux;    



        }
```

Scanner used:

```
 void run() throws Exception {


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)));
    int numCMD = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); // note that numCMD is >= N
    int index=0;//starting index at 0
    while (numCMD-- > 0) {
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
      index++;
      int command = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
      switch (command) {
        case 0: ArriveAtHospital(st.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())); 
               // you will need a index setter for this, assuming this is the moment when you add the patient to the patient list:
               ArriveAtHospìtalOrder(index);//as I cant see how the method ArriveAtHospital works, I showed you a possible method that takes the index.
               break;
        case 1: UpdateEmergencyLvl(st.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())); break;

        case 3: pr.println(Query()); break;
      }


    }
    pr.close();
```

This is a possible way, the ArriveAtHospitalIndex is just for illustrate, as I don't know exactly how you pass the parameters to the ArriveAtHospital method, this is just for you to know when the index should be passed. You have a little comment on the lines.